# Time column value change without touching it

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a "Trip" model that has "time" column that represents the trip time (in addition to the created_at and updated_at) columns. There's a hasOne relation between the "Trip" model and a "Bus" model (every bus can be associated to more than 1 trip). 
I want to set the "bus_id" column in the "Trips" table to null on deleting the corresponding bus. 
When I do so, something very strange happens, **the "time" column in the "Trips" table changes to the current time (similar to updated_at)**.

**Note:**

- This happens **only in this case**; any update to the "Trip" table doesn't change the column.
- When I inspect the code with `dd()`, I find the "time" column **unchanged**, but then the value is **changed in the database.**

Trip Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Trip extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['time', 'bus_id'];

    public function getStationsStringified(){
        $stations = $this->stations()->orderBy('order', 'asc')->pluck('name')->toArray();
        return implode(",", $stations);
    }

    public function bus(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Bus::class);
    }

    public function tickets(){
        return $this->hasMany(Ticket::class);
    }

    public function stations(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Station::class)->withPivot("order");
    }
}
```

Bus Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Bus extends Model
{
    //
    protected $fillable = ['license_num'];

    public function trips(){
        return $this->hasMany(Trip::class);
    }
}
```

Destroy function in BusController:

```
public function destroy($id){
        $bus = Bus::find($id);

        foreach ($bus->trips as $trip){
            if($trip->time < Carbon::now()->startOfDay()){
                $trip->bus()->dissociate();
                $trip->save();
            }else{
                return new Response("There a trip ".$trip->getStationsStringified()." associated with this bus, please change its bus before deletion", Response::HTTP_CONFLICT);
            }
        }

        $bus->delete();

        return new Response("Deleted", Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
```

Comment: Looks like your database table have sort of function. Check Time Column attribute in your database.

Comment: Yes, timestamp() in migration adds extra function on the column to set its value to current timestamp on update. I used time() instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I used `timestamp()` in the migrationn file defining the *trips table*, which adds automatically extra function on the *time column* **set to current time on update**.

The reason why the problem doesn't happen on any other updates is that I was setting a value to the *time column*.

The solution is to use `datetime()` in the migration instead of `timestamp()`.